# What is the advantage of buying an SSL certificate from the CA rather than a reseller?

Tags: tls, certificate-authority

I am trying to do some research on SSL certificates, and I've come across a number of reseller sites such as GoGetSSL, which offer certificates at much lower prices than what you would pay if you bought them directly from the certificate authority.  I understand resellers buy certificates in bulk which allows them to pass on discounts, but I can't understand what the advantage would be to go to the directly to the certificate authority?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is in most cases no real significant advantage in buying directly from the CA to my experience. Especially since the prices are often higher - resellers provide nearly the same value for less money (might depend on your specific needs though). If you take advantage of a promo by a reseller you may even get the first year for free or so.

The main difference that I observed is that in case you buy from a reseller the certificate lifecycle management processes and also support processes are also provided through the reseller and the CA usually does not support you if you contact them directly.

Apart from that I noticed that some non-standard or cutting edge features are sometimes not available through resellers, i.e. if you want to have your cert SHA-2 signed it may not be possible in every reseller/CA constellation. Best is to ask beforehand if you know that you have any special needs.

Comment: Thanks, I thought as much but it was difficult to find anywhere that stated this explicitly.  Much appreciated!